# Hibernate, weblogic 12c deployment error

Tags: java, hibernate, jbpm, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy a .war on weblogic 12c and I get the following error:
weblogic console error :

```
An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details. 
Error org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
getAuditTaskById, getAllAuditTasksByUser, getAllAuditTasks 
Error Substituted for missing class org.hibernate.HibernateException - 
Errors in named queries: getAuditTaskById, getAllAuditTasksByUser, getAllAuditTasks
```

I have tried to filter class path by changing weblogic.xml :

```
    <container-descriptor>
      <!-- prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes-->
      <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>   
    <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.apache.*</package-name>
      <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>

  </container-descriptor>
```

I am using hinernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar, hibernate-core-4.2.12.Final.jar , hibernate-entitymanaget-4.2.12.Final.jar . Any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Here is complete error log:

```
    <Apr 22, 2015 3:29:19 PM IRDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were
detected while initiating deploy task for application "benefits40".>
<Apr 22, 2015 3:29:19 PM IRDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace fo
r message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors i
n named queries: getAuditTaskById, getAllAuditTasksByUser, getAllAuditTasks
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(Extensi
bleModuleWrapper.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(Modu
leListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:175)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:170)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(Stat
eMachineDriver.java:80)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: getAuditTa
skById, getAllAuditTasksByUser, getAllAuditTasks
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.j
ava:532)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.jav
a:1797)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactor
yImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Con
figuration.java:914)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Con
figuration.java:899)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Apr 22, 2015 3:29:19 PM IRDT> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Co
nsole encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: org
.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: getAuditTaskById, getAll
AuditTasksByUser, getAllAuditTasks
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(Extensi
bleModuleWrapper.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(Modu
leListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:175)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleSta
teDriver.java:170)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(Stat
eMachineDriver.java:80)
        at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTunin
gWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Substituted for missing class org.hibernate.Hibe
rnateException - Errors in named queries: getAuditTaskById, getAllAuditTasksByUs
er, getAllAuditTasks
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.j
ava:532)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.jav
a:1797)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactor
yImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Con
figuration.java:914)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Con
figuration.java:899)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFa
ctory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
        at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.initializeEntityManagerF
actory(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:461)
        at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.initializeEntityManagerF
actory(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:454)
        at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.init(BasePersistenceUnit
Info.java:141)
        at weblogic.persistence.BaseJPAIntegrationProvider.createPersistenceUnit
Info(BaseJPAIntegrationProvider.java:54)
        at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.storeDescriptors
(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:423)
        at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceD
escriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:130)
        at weblogic.persistence.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(ModulePersi
stenceUnitRegistry.java:61)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension$PersistenceEx
tension.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:267)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension$PersistenceEx
tension.access$400(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:188)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension.prePrepare(We
bAppInternalModuleExtension.java:58)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateCha
nge.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:293)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateCha
nge.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineD
river.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(Extensi
bleModuleWrapper.java:109)
>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error:

```
Error org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries:
getAuditTaskById, getAllAuditTasksByUser, getAllAuditTasks
```

You have error in the JPQL in your named queries defined on top of some of your entities. If you dont know where those queries are defined, simply search your code files for the `getAuditTaskById, getAllAuditTasksByUser...` text, and fix the queries.

Comment: Dear Zielu, thank you very mush for your answer. These queries are inside some jar files from jbpm 6 libraries, not written by me. I guess these queries work fine, and problem is something else. I would be very thankful if you share your opinion with me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. There was a problem with my persistence.xml file. I was using this:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory" />
```

This uses the old hql parser, which is for hibernate 2.1 (or some version like that) and older versions. For newer versions of hibernate core, you must use this:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory" />
```

Or do not write anything for this property, and by default, ASTQueryTranslatorFactory will be chosen. I was using hibernate core 4.2.x , and some jar files from jbpm 6 that use some queries that ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory was unable to pars.
Note that if you have to use ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory alongside newer versions of hibernate core, it is possible to config hibernate so that it use this version of hql parser.